# How to give the path for the associated header files in alchemy?

Tags: c, apache-flex, alchemy

I am converting a speexdecoder code to C in alchemy. The problem is that i am importing a header file `#include <speex/speex.h>`. Alchemy gcc gives an error that speex.h not found.

I have placed the speex directory where my C code is.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder is local to your source, you shouldn't be using brackets (which tells the compiler to [look for the sources in the standard system folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)).  You should be using quotes:

```
#include "speex/speex.h"
```

Note that this isn't anything peculiar to Alchemy-- regular gcc works the same way.